# How do you tell if an AWS Snapshot has been deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to delete orphaned snapshots, but the query I am using keeps giving me snapshots that are deleted. Is there a query I can use to avoid deleted snapshots?

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-id snap-00012345cac2b3de1
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "DescriptionHere",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "OwnerId": "123456088429",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-00012345cac2b3de1",
            "StartTime": "2018-01-24T06:42:50+00:00",
            "State": "completed",
            "VolumeId": "vol-00123dc456ad5117",
            "VolumeSize": 6,
            "StorageTier": "standard"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is deleted?

Comment: When I check in the console, it is not there. I can also recreate this by deleting a volume and describing it.

Comment: Are you sure that the AWS CLI is pointing to the same region as your console? Or did you capture the Snapshot ID before deleting it, so you know it is definitely the same snapshot? It could be that the Snapshot is being used by an AMI, so the Snapshot stays around while the AMI still exists. But the management console should always show the same result as using the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK call.

Answer (score 1):

To test your situation, I did the following:

- Went to the EC2 Management Console and displayed Amazon EBS Volumes
- Created a Snapshot of an EBS Volume: `snap-036851d7351b78712`
- Ran `aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-id snap-036851d7351b78712`
- It returned a result similar yours
- Deleted the Snapshot in the Management Console
- Ran the above command again. The result was:

> An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.NotFound) when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation: The snapshot 'snap-036851d7351b78712' does not exist.

So, I was **unable to reproduce your situation**.

I then wondered whether **the Snapshot might be associated with an AMI**. I did the following:

- **Created an AMI** of an existing Amazon EC2 instance
- Waited until the AMI creation was complete
- Listed Snapshots in the console -- a new snapshot appeared `snap-047563373ab4c1088`
- I then tried to delete the snapshot, but received the message:

> snap-047563373ab4c1088: The snapshot snap-047563373ab4c1088 is currently in use by ami-0fc62425d087dbbe8

I then 'deregistered' (deleted) the AMI and it told me that the associated Snapshot would *not* be deleted:

[image: Deregister EC2 AMI]

- I then manually deleted the Snapshot in the console
- I used `describe-snapshots` and it said that the snapshot did not exist

So, perhaps your Snapshot is associated with an AMI and it was never actually deleted?